# how to set one value for few key's in YAML object

Tags: rest, api, yaml, openapi, swaggerhub

As far as I know there is no way to attach few keys to the single value in {key : value} pair in YAML. 
I am new to Swagger documentation (OpenAPI 3.0) and wondering is it possible somehow to combine my values together.
For instance, I am messing with REST API documentation and when I want to list few responses without rewriting it every time, I have the following :

```
paths:
  /users:
      post:
//some additional information here
        responses:
          '500':
//and for example here I want to add not only 201 status code but also others
                description: >-
                  Something went wrong on back end
//however I have to do something like this (writing them all)
          '502':
                description: >-
                  Something went wrong on back end
//and so on..
```

What is best practices to overcome that? Maybe I have a bad point from the beginning.

Comment: YAML comments start with `#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anchors and aliases:

```
path:
  /users:
    responses:
      '500':
        description: &desc1 >-
          Something went wrong on back end
      '502':
        description: *desc1
```

Comment: YAML anchors may or may not work depending on the OpenAPI parser used.

Comment: @Helen well OpenAPI explicitly specifies that a document may be represented as YAML and applies no restrictions to anchor/alias usage, so if a parser does not support it, that is a bug in the parser.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI 3.0 supports response ranges `'1XX'`-`'5XX'` that can be used instead of listing the codes individually:

```yaml
    responses:
      '5XX':
        description: Something went wrong on back end
```

If you still want to list the response codes individually but they have the same `description` and `schema`, you can `$ref` the common response definition like so:

```yaml
    responses:
      '501':
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/BackendErrorResponse'
      '502':
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/BackendErrorResponse'

components:
  responses:
    BackendErrorResponse:
      description: Something went wrong on back end
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            ...
```

There's also an enhancement request in the OpenAPI Specification repository to allow [reusing `description` across different responses](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1741).

Comment: Okay, I am very grateful for your help however there another question appeared.   So, for example I have managed my problem with your second solution and now I have the following responses:
 `responses: 
     BadRequest:
      description: Bad request
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/error'
    Unauthorized:
      description: Unauthorized
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/error'`
Is it possible somehow to reuse similar content?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not know how to format code in comments well.

Comment: If you mean reusing the `content` key, OpenAPI does not support `$ref`'erencing the `content` key, you can `$ref` either the whole response (description + content) or just the content `schema`. But you can try YAML anchors [as suggested by flyx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836457/113116). YAML anchors should work in Swagger Editor and Swagger UI, but I don't know about other tools.